# Storing Information without login

Tags: php

If any site visitor fills the form without login to the application then if he visits 
the site again from the same pc then he should be able to view his last filled
information.

But I do not have any idea how to do it.Its a PHP application.

Thanks
Gaurav

Comment: Check out sessions and cookies

Answer (score 1):

You can Track A record Of User's Ip So Its Value You Can Use When user filling up form

Comment: With dynamic ip's all over the place (most non corporate users) not that 'effective'.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to save the Information that the user provided into a cookie.
But cookies are handled by the browser and if the user has confed his browser to delete cookies after closing the info will get lost.

So it depends on the users browser setting if it will work.

(http://php.net/manual/de/function.setcookie.php)

Another Solution for newer Browsers would be to use the DOM Storage as Supercookie.
Or directly store the form information to the local storage.

Both are HTML5 features and not properly implemented in all browsers.

[dom-storage-super-cookie](http://webdevwonders.com/dom-storage-super-cookie/)

[html5_webstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are probably the best option but you could do this with html 5, javascript and [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Store the information in cookies. Read those back when the user visits again from the same browser and prefill your form elememts.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is the use of persistent cookies - they are attached to the browser and outlive sessions and Browser restarts. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Persistent_cookie

These cookies can be denied and removed if the user wants to.